# Timer scheduled timer in table view cell keep showing wrong index path row swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer

So basically I want to make an app like feeds (image and videos), that show timer only on video feeds. The problem is the timer shows not with the right duration timer. it shows the duration for the video feeds below/above it. I have tried to put the scheduled timer in cellForRowAt but it's not working so well. Can I know what is the better solution?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                                    let asset = AVAsset(url: (videoURL)!)
                                    let duration = asset.duration
                                    print("total time duration news feed : \(Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)))")

                                    self.countTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1 ,
                                                                           target: self,
                                                                           selector: #selector(self.changeTimer(_:)),
                                                                           userInfo: cell,
                                                                           repeats: true)
                                    self.timerInt = Int(Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)))
                                }
    }

    @objc func changeTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
            let cells = timer.userInfo as? FeedCell

            let minutes = timerInt / 60
            let seconds = timerInt % 60

            cells?.lblTimeCounter.isHidden = false

            if timerInt > 0 {
                print("change timer home feed : \(String(timerInt))")
                cells?.lblTimeCounter.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
                timerInt -= 1
            } else {
                cells?.lblTimeCounter.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
                self.countTimer?.invalidate()
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest that you don't use an integer to count elapsed time, and don't use `asyncAfter`.  Run a single `Timer` instance, say at 0.5s and update your data model to reflect elapsed time.  Take a `Date()` when an item starts playing and use `timeInvervalSinceNow` on that `Date` to determine the elapsed time.  Each time your timer fires you can iterate over the visible cells and update the elapsed time for the relevant cells.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't understand why use Date. because of the video duration, I can get from the URL. and single Timer instance is Timer.scheduled timer you mean?

Comment: Because `Timer` isn't always accurate; It can suffer from jitter.  Yes, a single `Timer.scheduledTimer` is what I mean.

Comment: I have not made the data model. what do I fill in the data model? @Paulw11

Comment: Whatever data you need for the cell; the video URL, the title, the start date (or calculate the end date by adding duration to the start date)

Comment: So the solutions are using Timer Instance ?? the problem are this for example the video durations are 3 s, 5 s , 9 s. sometimes the first video can show 5s instead of 3 s. @Paulw11

Comment: That won't happen if you hold your data in an array and onlynuodste the visible rows.  The problem with your current approach is that the asyncAfter can fire after the cell has been reused.

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay so where should I put the scheduled timer then?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` Is probably a good choice